# How get encoded string original length which contains \\ character in JavaScript, jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some problems with JavaScript. I get from the database, encoded strings and put its JavaScript array. string contains \\ and when I alert string length is greater than it has. how can I get the original string?
this is my string

```
var a = "eir~FdezuOha@ha_@rPzjQbnChxI~_Gf}\\|aAfnu@exNjmm@ilDvi]~Ttnz@tmLlyg@vi@nj`@`vIlrZznB`d^dd@zsVbvFdia@~bK~yT~uQxsPpmA|wL_bD|cCwiEfaEil@d`s@keEzri@u`Erw~Am|Dp{x@qJjbfBx}AdyrDkPtme@tgClei@feAziLrwFhJl}Ax`LvwHz||@nmHtrp@hGnnc@_D~j}@a@hskA_GjfuAlj]t_`@`sTheWjs@h{\\|AbxOj}LnxK`fN|gXtyH~cBrvElnKhaPxk`@jxB~v\\tqK~lLuUvkh@kBz~|As@tyfCfCbck@dbJhfh@h_QprrAcaC|czAunHbsr@qkMpm`@osk@|opB}nPvjvAthDp_kBhQdvt@zyK`pdAjlIx|OdiJln_@ngKzzu@l`YtdeAlqQrjZfzc@|y\\v{`@zks@h_@xcWf_CjoaArzNrbkAbfNb~c@nsVzeYjlTno]|hJxzU|~AflJvyDncJpnJdkKabBn`ToeE|pYcr@thRqpAh{NraHvkKnfCv}Js`@pmRx}EroV`dItwQnpQlcM~jAzrGikJdaHujMjxJs`@bxQzsEjlKmyCnrJc|FzrXu`FzhJ`eE`|LvfD`}`@rrDrr_@diHbdQbaBzrRajAd`[rzL~rwAtfDbhTn|HvvKluRvqWjiNxjHnlE|@ppKpfJbtDroDth@vre@oFnxRigF|nO{bEbwRwpGhmLld@rrKxuCbbRbnKbhSnve@vrr@}sBxqs@f{AnwZvZh{a@qnGdnSa~AlrKfmLjhe@q|AfmOj|FvlYzvE|br@j{Axr_@hkFfre@jhIdrg@udJbuRknHpbBgzBpdFc~AhyJorBzaOu|AffTpzFnaLv_W`{d@lhPrfJvxEfnJ~`KvuJ`nE~bTgzGztVwf@vsHngJ`eI~vV`yFv`m@sgAhhGwcC~iHtiH`ed@ruUbtO`tYv~Vlf^hdHlq@bnFvqLxin@p|Rxp[rkWnyTzka@jtVfqLvtF|aa@vcF`|Erc@~cIp}MjyUzuC|{O`lGp~Qhn@|rc@~mS|eg@vtZzi_@hqL|uSpkOrqHldHhkHl|Kjk[bgLdxItqa@jtDjiPbbDhwQryQlou@beVh|LnrJw}@~yRdk`@hhsAf~RtwSnbRblZp|CtgZfs]radA~~Bf_[zvArjTrcFfjNtzb@xgWziUtsN|af@tp\\blEluFpuFmsDn|FaoCdwCqlB~hFb|D|nMthQl_FfvFsxA|tYl|AnwP_Fzca@zbApjr@x]xP"


alert(a.length) //length is 1279

$.ajax({
    cache : false,
    url : 'get_polylines.action',
    type : 'post',
    dataType : 'json',
    async : false,
    success : function(result) {
       var polyline = result.polyline;

       var arr = new Array();
       var k = 0;
       for ( var j = 0; j < polyline.length; j++) {
          arr [k] = polyline[j];
          k++;
       }
      for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
        alert(arr[i].length); //length is 1284
       }
    },
    
});
```

When I put this string in input hidden field and then get value it also alerts length 1284.

Comment: `arr[i].length` would throw an exception.

Comment: But `arr` doesn't appear to have any content at the point at which you're trying to find its length..?

Comment: I put a value in the array just not wrote this part

Comment: Please post all the relevant code, like variable initialisations, @Lusi.

Comment: What do yo mean by original length? `"\\".length` is 1.

Comment: `arr[i]` return a single character i mean value at `ith` position in an array and `length` method is not defined on single value variable.that would be the reason i guess.

Comment: I think that \ this character break word to  new line, and that reason that I get 1284 but its length is 1279.

Comment: 1284 is actually the correct length of that string. Copy the string to a text editor and see for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.split()` to cut up your array, instead of looping through the string:

```
var a = "eir~FdezuOha@ha_@rPzjQbnChxI~_Gf}\\|aAfnu@exNjmm@ilDvi]~Ttnz@tmLlyg@vi@nj`@`vIlrZznB`d^dd@zsVbvFdia@~bK~yT~uQxsPpmA|wL_bD|cCwiEfaEil@d`s@keEzri@u`Erw~Am|Dp{x@qJjbfBx}AdyrDkPtme@tgClei@feAziLrwFhJl}Ax`LvwHz||@nmHtrp@hGnnc@_D~j}@a@hskA_GjfuAlj]t_`@`sTheWjs@h{\\|AbxOj}LnxK`fN|gXtyH~cBrvElnKhaPxk`@jxB~v\\tqK~lLuUvkh@kBz~|As@tyfCfCbck@dbJhfh@h_QprrAcaC|czAunHbsr@qkMpm`@osk@|opB}nPvjvAthDp_kBhQdvt@zyK`pdAjlIx|OdiJln_@ngKzzu@l`YtdeAlqQrjZfzc@|y\\v{`@zks@h_@xcWf_CjoaArzNrbkAbfNb~c@nsVzeYjlTno]|hJxzU|~AflJvyDncJpnJdkKabBn`ToeE|pYcr@thRqpAh{NraHvkKnfCv}Js`@pmRx}EroV`dItwQnpQlcM~jAzrGikJdaHujMjxJs`@bxQzsEjlKmyCnrJc|FzrXu`FzhJ`eE`|LvfD`}`@rrDrr_@diHbdQbaBzrRajAd`[rzL~rwAtfDbhTn|HvvKluRvqWjiNxjHnlE|@ppKpfJbtDroDth@vre@oFnxRigF|nO{bEbwRwpGhmLld@rrKxuCbbRbnKbhSnve@vrr@}sBxqs@f{AnwZvZh{a@qnGdnSa~AlrKfmLjhe@q|AfmOj|FvlYzvE|br@j{Axr_@hkFfre@jhIdrg@udJbuRknHpbBgzBpdFc~AhyJorBzaOu|AffTpzFnaLv_W`{d@lhPrfJvxEfnJ~`KvuJ`nE~bTgzGztVwf@vsHngJ`eI~vV`yFv`m@sgAhhGwcC~iHtiH`ed@ruUbtO`tYv~Vlf^hdHlq@bnFvqLxin@p|Rxp[rkWnyTzka@jtVfqLvtF|aa@vcF`|Erc@~cIp}MjyUzuC|{O`lGp~Qhn@|rc@~mS|eg@vtZzi_@hqL|uSpkOrqHldHhkHl|Kjk[bgLdxItqa@jtDjiPbbDhwQryQlou@beVh|LnrJw}@~yRdk`@hhsAf~RtwSnbRblZp|CtgZfs]radA~~Bf_[zvArjTrcFfjNtzb@xgWziUtsN|af@tp\\blEluFpuFmsDn|FaoCdwCqlB~hFb|D|nMthQl_FfvFsxA|tYl|AnwP_Fzca@zbApjr@x]xP"
arr = a.replace(/\\/g,"\\\\").split("");
console.log(arr.length); //1284
```

So replace the "success" bit of your ajax call with this:

```
success : function(result) {
   var polyline = result.polyline;

    var arr = polyline.replace(/\\/g,"\\\\").split("");
    var k = arr.length; //1284
}
```

The reason different lengths are being output is because you have backslash (`"\"`) characters in your string. These are normally used to escape special characters, and will need to be escaped before building a array from the string.
The replacement is done with `.replace(/\\/g,"\\\\")`, replacing all single backslashes (`"\"`) with doubles (`"\\"`). This results in the array returning a length of 1284, wich is actually correct:

```
console.log(arr);
==> [<...> "G", "f", "}", "\", "\", "|", "a", "A", <...>]
//Representing:
"Gf}\\|aA";
```

Comment: Thanks for answer.
That string represents encoded direction which provide google map api, and i store that encoded direction in my db. when i get from db that direction and draw it in map it draws wrong direction, and when I try your suggession (replace from \\ to  \\\\) it also draws wrong direction, but when i draw var a it draws direction correctly